# Set local_tmp as an ansible variable

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to set [local_tmp](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/intro_configuration.html#local-tmp) as a variable in a playbook or pass it on the command-line instead? The only way, as I see it, to set this variable is by writing it to a file in a pre-determined location or by creating the file in an arbitrary location and setting the environment variable `ANSIBLE_CONFIG` to point to it.

What I want is to overrirde the default value of `local_tmp` by specifying it on either the command-line or in a playbook.

Comment: Are you aware of [`$ANSIBLE_LOCAL_TEMP`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/config.html#default-local-tmp)? It's super unfortunate that it has a different name from the config key, though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
ANSIBLE_LOCAL_TEMP=/tmp/.ansible/tmp ansible-playbook myplaybook.yml
```